# Qt serial communication

Tags: c++, qt

I just tried the following code. But the slot function is not working. The connection is OK and I found out it by qDubug. The console output is as follows.

```
[ZDSGuard] 32 DllMain hook strProductName2 : C:\qt_example\build- 
serial_test-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\debug\serial_test.exe-1
ddd
ss
ccc
```

As you can find, `aaa` is not printed out. If the slot function works fine, it should be printed.

Please let me know if somebody finds out what is wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

```
[ZDSGuard] 32 DllMain hook strProductName2 : C:\qt_example\build- 
serial_test-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug\debug\serial_test.exe-1
ddd
ss
ccc
```

Serial Communication Code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>


QSerialPort *serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serial = new QSerialPort();
    serial->setPortName("COM4");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
       ui->label->setText("bb");
    if (QObject::connect(serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(serialReceived())))
        qDebug()<< "ddd";
    //ui->label->setText("aa");
    qDebug() << "ss";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;

    serial->close();
}

void MainWindow::serialReceived()
{
    QByteArray BA;
    BA=serial->readAll();
    ui->label->setText("aa");
    //printf(BA);
    qDebug()<<"aaa";//BA;
}
```

Comment: Did you send data from the other end of the connection?

Answer (score 0):

QSP has bug in Qt 5.13.1. Use or Qt 5.13.0, or wait for a newest versions (5.13.2 / 5.12.6).